# Rock song with lyric "walking in your shoes", gruff voice singer like Linkin Park

Tags: lyrics, rock, identify-this-song

There's a rock (or metal) popular song, not recent probably. It has these phrases (sort of).

"walking in your shoes"
"something i am not gonna say to you"
"i love you"
"and every second i"

Can anybody please help me figure out what this song is? Male voice, not a long song, not recent, metal/rock-ish, gruffy voice like In the End -- Linkin Park, and probably popular.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might be thinking of another Linkin Park song, "[Numb](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXYiU_JCYtU)". Looking at [the lyrics](http://genius.com/Linkin-park-numb-lyrics), it has a few lines very close to the ones you remembered from it (emphasis mine), but it's missing "something I am not gonna say to you" and "I love you".

> Put under the pressure of **walking in your shoes**
>
> ---
>
> **And every second I** waste is more than I can take

And obviously, the gruff voice that sounds like the one in "In The End" would be the same guy. :)

Answer (score -1):

Probably you also are looking for Placebo song titled "Wouldn't It Be Good" its really popular and quite classic rock song :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LApkZTatMIU